# Delete query from SQL Server 2008 to linked Postgres

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

I want to delete some data from SQL Server 2008 in linked PostpresSQL.
I found this solution:

```
--DELETE data
DELETE FROM
OpenQuery('MSDASQL','SELECT  name  FROM sometable wHERE name LIKE ''test%'' ')
```

but how can I delete some data from SQL Server query in PostgresSQL?

Query from SQL Server

```
select name from myMSSQL_table
```

Comment: I have seen quite a view attempts to re-invent the name of PostgreSQL, but `PostpresSQL` is new.

Answer (score 0):

DELETE data on linked server if user rights maped properly
run the same as normal SQL DELETE command, with full object names:

```
DELETE FROM [PGSQL].[demodata].[dbo].[tbl_Master]
SELECT * FROM [PGSQL].[demodata].[dbo].[tbl_Master]
```

> [Name of Linked Server].[database].[schema].[table]

Comment: i cant get access to PostgreSQL via normal sql.
`SELECT *  [PSQLLINK].[mbd].[public].[table_all_bs_copy]`
Only via
`OpenQuery('MSDASQL','SELECT  name  FROM sometable wHERE name LIKE ''test%'' ')`

Comment: Why not proper setup Linked Server? Main idea of linked data - have direct access as for local tables. Any other restrictions with setup?

Comment: Some time answer based on other version and may be incorrect, my default server 2014, special add PostgreSQL as Linked to 2008 - delete and select work as normal